# Trying to develop an in Android, MediaPlayer plays two songs ath the same time

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android app developing, and I've tried to program a very simple app: each time the headphone cable is inserted it will play a random song from the collection, and stop whenever the headphone cable is disconnected.

However, I now face a very strange problem: no matter what I do, the app plays always two songs at the same time.

It's very strange because I tried to synchronize everything but it didn't solve the issue...

Here follows my code. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int countMusic;

    private boolean headphones= false;

    private HeadphonePlugReceiver receiver;

    private HashMap<Integer, String> playing_title;

    private RandomPlayer player;

    Object lock = new Object();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playing_title = new HashMap<>();

        scanAgain();

        Button scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_again);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                scanAgain();
            }
        });

        updateStatus();

        receiver = new HeadphonePlugReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
    }

    private void updateStatus() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView statusTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
                TextView titleTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

                    if (headphones) {
                        statusTextView.setText("Headphones connected!");
                        String txt = "";
                        for (Integer cd: playing_title.keySet()) {
                            txt += String.format("%d: %s ### ", cd, playing_title.get(cd).replace("_", " "));
                        }
                        titleTextView.setText(txt);
                    } else {
                        statusTextView.setText("Headphones not connected.");
                        titleTextView.setText("Music not playing");
                    }

            }
        });

    }

    private void addDebug(final String code) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView debugTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.debug);
                String dbg = String.format("%s \n %s", debugTextView.getText(), code);
                debugTextView.setText(dbg);

            }
        });

    }

    private void addError(final String msg) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView errorTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error);
                errorTextView.setText(msg);

            }
        });

    }

    private void startPlayer() {

            if (player == null) {
                player = new RandomPlayer(this);
                player.start();

        }
    }

    private void stopPlayer() {

            if (player != null) {
                player.interr();
                player = null;
            }

    }

    private void scanAgain() {
        try {
        TextView countTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.count);
        countTextView.setText("Scanning... ");
        countMusic = scanMusic().getCount();
        countTextView.setText(String.format("Music file found: %d", countMusic));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("problem", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Cursor scanMusic() {
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE_KEY
        };
        Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
        return cur;
    }


    private class HeadphonePlugReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", 0);

                managePlayer(state);
                // Log.e("state", String.format("state: %d", state));
            }
        }

        private void managePlayer(int state) {
            boolean n_headphones = (state != 0);
            if (n_headphones == headphones)
                return;
            headphones = n_headphones;
            if (headphones)
                startPlayer();
            else
                stopPlayer();
        }
    }

    private class RandomPlayer extends Thread implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

        private final MainActivity act;
        private final Random r;
        private final int code;

        private MediaPlayer mp;
        private boolean keep_going = true;

        Object lock2 = new Object();

        public RandomPlayer(MainActivity mainActivity) {
            r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            act = mainActivity;
            code = r.nextInt(10000);
        }

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            playNext();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            playNext();

            while (keep_going) {
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    keep_going = false;
                }
            }

            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
            }

            playing_title.remove(code);

            updateStatus();
        }

        public void interr() {
    keep_going = false;
}


        private void playNext() {

            synchronized (lock2) {


                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = null;
                }

                mp = new MediaPlayer();
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                //mp.setVolume(0.9f , 0.9f);
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

            int chosen = r.nextInt(countMusic);

            Cursor cur = scanMusic();
            for (int i = 0; i < chosen; i++)
                cur.moveToNext();


                playing_title.put(code, cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));

            try {
                int a1 = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                String a2 = cur.getString(a1);
                mp.setDataSource(a2);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
                addDebug(a2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Randomplayer", "exception", e);
                addError(e.getMessage());
            }

             updateStatus();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to put together an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - it'll make it easier for people to ascertain what's wrong.

Comment: Well, in the code provided there is all the logic of the app, regarding the question. What else do you think I should provide?

Comment: Not "what else"; "what less" ;) Have a look at the 'minimal' part of what I linked to. Someone may be able to help anyway, but I'm just suggesting what may make it easier for people to help.